# Is it possible to disable the Node module?

Tags: 7

Is it possible to disable the Node module in Drupal 7?

As I understand from the interface, it is not possible. Why is the Node module is so important? What if I'm going to use only custom entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7 the answer is no, it's a piece of functionality built into the system more than required by anything else. I've heard rumors long ago maybe in Drupal 8 it would not need to be enabled by default -- but I'm not sure of that status now.

It's needed for example because it provides paths to content on the site at `node/NID` by *non-developers* -- yes `Entities` can do that. Drupal caters to a wide range of audiences, not just those that understand what a `Node` is and what an `Entity` is. In Drupal 8 there may be an install profile which is super minimal to even not include any content types, I'm not sure what happened regarding that ... ah in Drupal 8 they still require the `Node` module in the `Minimal` profile installer:
https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.0.x/core/profiles/minimal/minimal.info.yml

If you want to use entities then use a module like [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) to hide any node content and do not use default nodes at all.

Comment: Drupal 8 requires the node module in minimal profile *because* it is optional now. It wouldn't be necessary to mention it there explicitly if it would still be a required module. It mostly affects tests, where neither node, nor filter nor text.module are enabled by default. And quite possibly soon also field.module. Then there will be exactly two really required modules left: system (which is dying a very very slow death) and user.module.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Actually I just hoped to shut down node completely, I just do not need nodes functionality at all.